# roman page numbers problems OT2

Tags: cyrillic, roman, page

I have a problem. I am writing a book in Cyrillic, but the numbers of pages are marked in roman letters also written in Cyrillic. How can they be written in Latin only? Instead of i, ii, iii,.. writes и,ии,иии,...

Comment: What do you mean by “in Roman letters also written in Cyrillic”?

Comment: Instead of i, ii, iii,.. writes и,ии,иии,...

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code producing the issue.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}  
\usepackage{amstext,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[OT1,OT2]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  

\newcommand{\lat}{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
    \include{Naslovna}

\mainmatter 
    \include{Gl_1}

{\pagestyle{index}
    \include{Indeks}
}
\end{document}

Comment: Please, add the code to the question

Comment: Excuse me, what's this code? I'm not from the English speaking field.

Comment: The example code you showed in the comment should be an edit to the question. Anyway, the problem seems to be in you using `OT2`; isn't typing directly Cyrillic better for you?

Comment: @BranislavM Have you seen my code for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I'm not at home right now!

Answer (score 2):

It would be much better to use T2A rather than OT2. Anyway, here is how you can do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[OT1,OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,serbian]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% let's use scalable fonts
\DeclareFontFamily{OT2}{cmr}{\hyphenchar\font45 }
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{it}{<->wncyi10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{sc}{<->wncysc10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{b}{n}{<->wncyb10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{bx}{n}{<->ssub*wncyr/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT2}{cmr}{m}{sl}{<->ssub*wncyr/m/it}{}


\newcommand{\lat}{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlat}{\lat}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@roman}[1]{%
  \textlat{\romannumeral #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Увод}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I put in what you wrote to me, I get an error message

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ursfs.fd")
! Argument of \@tforloop has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.53 \end{titlepage}
                    
?

Comment: @BranislavM Your code doesn't load `rsfs`, so I can't tell more about the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I`ve changed code as you suggested and problem was solved -for the moment, but now new problem is arising . The problem is with names that are written on the pages where the previous problem existed : after changing the code, those names are not showing in Index. If I switch to the old code,names are listed in the Index but than pages are marked in Cyrilic  letters.

Comment: @BranislavM Please, make a new question with the details about indexing.

Comment: Dear Sir, I have succeeded in following your instructions to resolve the problem I have written about. Thank you very much! Now I noticed a new problem occurred to me: The names of the mathematicians who are on pages marked as you wrote (pages are marked in roman letters) are not visible on the Index name page. I hope you will help me! Greeting!

Comment: @BranislavM Not without an example of what you're doing, in a new question.

Comment: How can I send print screen two pages to show you examples?

Comment: @BranislavM Not images, but code

Comment: \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[name=person,title={Indeks imena},options=-s index_style.ist]

\index[person]{Birch, Brajan|text}

Comment: @BranislavM Sorry, but that's not sufficient. Please, open a new question with a short example of code, but it should be a document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106245/discussion-between-branislavm-and-egreg).